# OnChange Uncaught TypeError: Not a Function on element created by template literals from the same Class

Tags: javascript, class, methods, template-literals

I have an issue calling a method onChange from an element created by template literals. The element (checkbox) is created from the same class that includes a method that should be called by the `onChange` event. I have the following two JS files. main.js and class1.js

main.js:

```
import {CustomClass} from './customClass.js';
let customClass= new CustomClass();
customClass.createCheckBox();
```

customClass.js:

```
export class CustomClass{
     createCheckBox(){
        return `<input type="checkbox" onchange='customClass.customMethod()'`>
     }
     customMethod(){
        ...//some functionality
     }
}
```

When I select the checkbox I either get `Uncaught TypeError: this.customMethod() is not a function` or I get `undefined`. I tried to add `this` into `onchange='this.customMethod()` but I can't get it working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `createCheckbox()` just returns an HTML string, nothing is adding it to the DOM so you can click on it.

Comment: The error message doesn't match the code you've shown. The error message says `this.customMethod()`, but the code is `customClass.customMethod()`. The latter should work.